# Analysing peaks in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pandas

I have these data-set which consist of close to perfectly spaced peaks. The peaks are not dirac delta functions but more of a gaussian shape. I need to analyze the distance between the peaks very precisely using python. 
[image]

I am a beginner at python so I would really appreciate some help. 
The files are of the type `.csv` and `.h5`.

(I found out that the `.csv` files got too big for large samples so I had to switch to `.h5`.)

In my analyzing so far I have used the `pandas`-package and `numpy`-package and my guess is that they would also be able to solve this problem for me.

So I got this idea that I can filter out specific points on the peaks so. I tried this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#data = [time,voltage]
data1 = pd.read_csv('1pps_withoutReference.csv', sep=',')

#Plot data
time = data1["x"];
voltage = data1["y"];
plt.plot(time,voltage)
plt.show()

t = data1["x"];
v = data1["y"];

if n+1>4 and n-1<4: n=n;
else v.remove('n');
for n in v;
```

I guess the idea of what I am trying to do in that last part is pretty clear but it is simply not working. 
I only wnat the points where the point right before is less than 4 and the point right after is above. This should give me discrete values and would only result in a tiny offset which is not really relevant since I am looking for the distance between the peaks.

I have solved the problem by the help of a friend.

```
#getting t values for every peak.
time = data1["x"]
volt = data1["y"]

trig_lev = 2.5
#Creating new vector to contain the values of the peaks
t_peak = []
#For-loop updating the list with the disired values
for i in np.arange(0, len(time)):
    if volt[i] < trig_lev and volt[i+1] >= trig_lev:
    t_peak.append(time[i])
```

Comment: What have you tried(please show some code indicating where you are stuck at), and how do you define the difference(ie from centre to centre, from sigma=1)?

Comment: Can you upload somewhere your data in CSV/h5 format and post here a link to it?

Comment: The Fourier Transform of a comb is a comb. If your comb shows any deviations, like a chirp (change in spatial frequency), that you shoud be visible as broadening in the FT. The first frequency peak in the FFT will correspond to the spacing. The more peaks you have in the `time` domain the narrower would that peak be. The width of that first peak is not a limit on your accuracy, but a reflection of the time-bandwidth product. You could make a parabolic fit of that peak to get your spacing with best accuracy. In general google `frequency estimation`.

Comment: Physical examples are pulses from a modelocked laser, where the frequency spectrum shows a comb, and the diffraction from a grating that shows multiple orders in the spatial frequency domain.

Comment: @M.T, I have added what I have in mind. Can you correct this code for me? Or do you meybe have a better idea?

Answer (score 1):

Let me construct a fake `v` and `t` array for an example.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: v = np.random.random(20)*10

In [3]: t = np.arange(len(v))
```

Now, let's find all the values in `v` between 3 and 5.

```
In [4]: cond = np.logical_and(v < 5, v > 3)

In [5]: cond
Out[5]: 
array([False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False, False], dtype=bool)
```

This works because a `<` or `>` operation on an array of numbers returns an array of Boolean values.

```
In [6]: v
Out[6]: 
array([ 2.82501842,  9.28107914,  8.48711041,  4.61051569,  1.77473463,
        7.69499025,  9.74680202,  1.37199899,  6.34510291,  2.33337724,
        2.22011283,  6.63674361,  9.20012545,  5.80648649,  4.43828229,
        1.4105842 ,  2.72444927,  2.09571288,  5.80758599,  1.73408051])

In [7]: v < 5
Out[7]: 
array([ True, False, False,  True,  True, False, False,  True, False,
        True,  True, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,
       False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [8]: v > 3
Out[8]: 
array([False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,
       False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False,
        True, False], dtype=bool)
```

The `logical_and` function combines the two Boolean arrays.

Now isolate the `t` values where this condition is met.

```
In [9]: ix = [y for y, u in zip(t, cond) if u]

In [10]: ix
Out[10]: [3, 14]
```

Check the `v` values.

```
In [11]: [v[i] for i in ix]
Out[11]: [4.611, 4.438]
```

Comment: I don't really think this solves my problem? This will just give me the values of t for which   3.5 >   v  > 2.5 right? I want the values of t for which v+1>4 and v-1<4.

Comment: @Nillo I was illustrating the *principle*. `v+1>4` is `v>3` and `v-1<4` is `v<5`. So effectively `3<v<5`.

Comment: oh.. that is how you understand it! Sorry for being unclear. I want v+1>4 and v-1<4 as in the datapoints "v+1" and "v-1". Meaning that "v" is the datapoint between the points "v+1" and "v-1".

Comment: @Nillo Given the geometry of the signal, why would that be better? With your formula, you are *basically* looking for a derivative. But the derivative of an impulse function is also an impulse function.